# 302 from an AJAX request

Tags: ajax, http

I send an AJAX request which returns a 302 (I see this using fiddler) but in firebug I never see the 302. I just see a 500.

Same thing happens with IE.

If an AJAX request returns a 302 do browsers swallow it?

Thanks

Comment: They certainly won't swallow it, I'm not sure they can make a bird out of a http response...

Comment: I do not think that an AJAX call will perform the recursive lookup/redirect that happens with a normal browser response to a standard 302 ...

Comment: I fail at selecting the correct link; this is probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770289/how-to-catch-an-expected-and-intended-302-ajax-response

Answer (score 2):

When performing an AJAX POST in my web application, I found that my browser was registering a 302 Found, followed by a 200 OK.

[image: Browser network inspector]

However, the JavaScript debugger showed the response as being a 200 OK, with the HTML content to be shown on the redirection page.

[image: Browser JavaScript inspector]

This demonstrates that the redirection is being handled internally by JavaScript. In this case, you could replace the page's content with that returned by the server's response.

```
document.open();
document.write(xhr.responseText);
document.close();
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387688/replace-current-page-with-ajax-content) for more details.